# how can I use extends Model for model in Laravel, even if I have belongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, pivot

I know when we have many to many relationship, we have to use extends Pivot for model. But I dont want to use extends Pivot, I want to use extends Model. But the data cannot enter into db if I use extends Model for model in Laravel.

This is addPromo function in controller, in this function you should see this line. "events" is a function from Model

```
if (!$promoApplicableAllEvent) {
            $createPromoObj->events()->attach($request->selectedEventInput);
        }
```

```
 public function addPromoDB(Request $request,$validatedData,$promoExpiredDate,$promoDiscountAmount,$promoApplicableAllMenu,$promoApplicableAllCombo,$promoApplicableAllEvent,$menuIdArray,$menuPricingIdArray) {
        // --Create new promo data.
        $createPromoObj = new Promo;
        $createPromoObj->promo_name = $validatedData['promo_name'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_code = $validatedData['promo_code'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_expired_date = $promoExpiredDate;
        $createPromoObj->promo_min_purchase = $validatedData['promo_min_purchase'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_times_of_use_per_customer = $validatedData['promo_times_of_use_per_customer'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_code_total = $validatedData['promo_code_total'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_left = $validatedData['promo_code_total'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_type_selection = $validatedData['promo_type_selection'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_type = $validatedData['promo_type'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_type_setting = $validatedData['promo_type_setting'];
        $createPromoObj->promo_discount_amount = $promoDiscountAmount;
        $createPromoObj->promo_applicable_all_menu = $promoApplicableAllMenu;
        $createPromoObj->promo_applicable_all_combo = $promoApplicableAllCombo;
        $createPromoObj->promo_applicable_all_event = $promoApplicableAllEvent;
        $createPromoObj->promo_status = $request->boolean('is_draft') ? false : true;

        $createPromoObj->save();

        if (!$promoApplicableAllMenu) {
            $pivotData = [];
            foreach ($menuIdArray as $index => $menuId) {
                $pivotData[$menuId] = ['menu_pricing_id' => $menuPricingIdArray[$index]];
            }
            $createPromoObj->menus()->attach($pivotData);
        }

        if (!$promoApplicableAllCombo) {
            $createPromoObj->combos()->attach($request->selectedComboInput);
        }

        if (!$promoApplicableAllEvent) {
            $createPromoObj->events()->attach($request->selectedEventInput);
        }
    }
```

The "events" that I said will straightly go to here:

```
 public function events(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'promo_events')->using(PromoEvent::class);
    }
```

Because of im using BelongsToMany, the PromoEvent need to use extends Pivot, instead of extends Model. This is PromoEvent model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PromoEvent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class, 'event_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

I dont want to use PromoEvent extends Pivot but I want to use extends Model, but the data not store into DB if I use extends Model.

This is my promos model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;

class Promo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'promos';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'promo_name',
        'promo_code',
        'promo_expired_date',
        'promo_min_purchase',
        'promo_times_of_use',
        'promo_times_of_use_per_customer',
        'promo_code_total',
        'promo_left',
        'promo_type_selection',
        'promo_type',
        'promo_type_setting',
        'promo_discount_amount',
        'promo_applicable_all_menu',
        'promo_applicable_all_combo',
        'promo_applicable_all_event',
        'promo_status'
    ];

    // --Construct the promo status.
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('promo_status', true);
    }

    // Bulk delete function
    public function bulkDeletePromo($promoIds)
    {
        return Promo::whereIn('id', $promoIds)
            ->delete();
    }

    /**
     * The menu that belong to the Promo
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    */
    public function menus(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class, 'promo_menus')->using(PromoMenu::class)->withPivot('menu_pricing_id');
    }

    /**
     * The combo that belong to the Promo
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    */
    public function combos(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Combo::class, 'promo_combos')->using(PromoCombo::class);
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'promo_events')->using(PromoEvent::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'promo_id', 'id');
    }

    public function outlets()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function promoMenu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PromoMenu::class, 'promo_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And this is my event model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,SoftDeletes;

    public $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'available_session' => 'array',
        'available_outlet' => 'array',
    ];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you extend the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot` model, Laravel automatically takes that name and turns it into the adjacent table name by splitting each word of the model name and concatenating them with an underscore in the singular form.

For example:
If we have the model `PromoEvent`, Laravel expects a database table named `event_promo` to exist.

Notice how Laravel also orders the names alphabetically.

However, in the case you're extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, you can manually change the table name through the `$table` property inside your model, that's because Laravel will try to look for a database table named as `promo_events`

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PromoEvent extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // Specify table name manually
    protected $table = "promo_event";

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class, 'event_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

More information on this topic can be found at the following links:

- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#table-names
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure

Comment: I already tried, its not working :'(

Comment: @NajwaIsmail Can you share the code for both Event and Promo models ?

Comment: Okay done sharing by editing the question, cause i dont know how to share at the comment